# Jmeter to send Cookie with double quotes

Tags: javascript, api, cookies, jmeter

We are trying to use cookie manager to add cookie with " in its value.  We are not getting expected result due to wrong cookie value sent to API. Jmeter added \ for each " which makes cookie value different. I tried adding same cookie in chrome console using java script method. I did used \ as escape character for " while adding. But Chrome send cookie value without \ in request header. But its not happening in jmeter which is causing the error in our API call. Is there anyway we can pass " in cookie value in JMETER without the issue mentioned above? Appreciate your help.

Comment: which version of jmeter are you using ? which coolie policy ?

Answer (score 1):

In the [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) set "Cookie Policy" to `netscape`

[image: JMeter Cookie Policy Netscape]

This should make JMeter less restrictive in terms of HTTP protocol specification strict following therefore you will be able to send almost whatever you want:

[image: JMeter cookie quotation marks]

More information:

- [HTTP State Management Mechanism](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt)
- [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)